# MySQL - MySQL event scheduler will not transfer data from one table to another on a set frequency

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

At the moment I have two tables in my database. One of them have 10 entries/rows. I want to transfer random rows from this table onto the other with a limit of 3. I have created an event as described below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
EVENT minute
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2016-08-31 15:30:00'
DO BEGIN

    INSERT INTO table2 (Name, Email, Work, Week)
    SELECT Name, Email, Work, Week
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Why won't the desired columns and random rows transfer to the second table with a one minute frequency?

Comment: Has the event scheduler been enabled? It's not enough to create the event only, you have to enable the scheduler for events to work.

Comment: Yes it should be on. Activated it with SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;. But it still won't work. In SHOW PROCESSLIST it says event_scheduler db=NULL and state=Waiting for next activation.

Comment: Try to run the query manually, without the event. Check if it works. I'd start there. Otherwise, if scheduler is on and the event is created, it does get executed. It just might be the query is bad.

Comment: For some reason it just started working. Refreshed the page and there it was. Thanks for your help nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by altering the registered time in schedule. I was working with local time while the server was set at it's local time (2 hours before my local time).